# Gstreamer pipeline - produce and consume output in separate processes

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I want to have two separate gstreamer pipelines, one producing a video output, the other consuming it. **The producer is in a Docker container, and the consumer is running on the host.** For this I'm trying to get even the most basic thing imaginable working with `gst-launch` tool, but I just can't get it working no matter what. For example, this fails on the receiving end with `ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpVRawDepay:rtpvrawdepay0: No RTP format was negotiated.`:

```sh
# process to produce video stream:
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=3 \
  videotestsrc ! videoconvert \
  ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5600

# process to consume it (and display it):
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=3 \
  udpsrc port=5600 \
  ! rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

...what boggles my ming is that a seeming much more complex setup I do manage to get working:

```sh
# produce:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/path/to/my.mp4 \
  ! decodebin ! videoconvert \
  ! x264enc tune=zerolatency \
  ! rtph264pay \
  ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5600

# consume:
gst-launch-1.0 -vc udpsrc port=5600 close-socket=false multicast-iface=false auto-multicast=true \
  ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 \
  ! fpsdisplaysink  sync=false async=false --verbose
```

(Note: special sink type in second example doesn't matter, using `autovideosink` also works fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems you want to do this on the same host. Thats great, so we can forget about the complexity of network protocols and transmission.

GStreamer offers different ways to do this. I would recommend to look at `gdp` plugin:

```
Plugin Details:
  Name                     gdp
  Description              Payload/depayload GDP packets
  Filename                 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstgdp.so
  Version                  1.16.0
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-plugins-bad
  Source release date      2019-04-19
  Binary package           GStreamer Bad Plugins (Debian)
  Origin URL               http://packages.qa.debian.org/gst-plugins-bad1.0

  gdpdepay: GDP Depayloader
  gdppay: GDP Payloader

  2 features:
  +-- 2 elements
```

In combination with the `shm` plugin:

```
Plugin Details:
  Name                     shm
  Description              shared memory sink source
  Filename                 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstshm.so
  Version                  1.16.0
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-plugins-bad
  Source release date      2019-04-19
  Binary package           GStreamer Bad Plugins (Debian)
  Origin URL               http://packages.qa.debian.org/gst-plugins-bad1.0

  shmsink: Shared Memory Sink
  shmsrc: Shared Memory Source

  2 features:
  +-- 2 elements
```

Doing so lets you pass the complete `GstBuffer` data between processes. That means with all the time stamps, flags, etc.

So basically the producer does something like this:

```
.. ! gdppay ! shmsink
```

and the consumer:

```
shmsrc ! gdpdepay ! ..
```

Set the properties and socket path accordingly..

I guess a regular file/pipe via `filesink/filesrc` would work to, but I have not tried..

Comment: Thanks, but, sorry for not being more explicit: technically the two processes are not on the same machine... well, actually, **the producer is inside a docker container and the consumer is running on the host**... that's why I started down this path of using udp(src/sink)

Comment: actually made it work by copying the caps (show via `-v` flag) from the producer udpsink to the `caps` attribute of the consumer's udpsink... and now I have it working when running directly on same machine, but still no luck with the docker setup, guess there must be something messing up the ports or messing up container -> host traffic in some other f way...

Comment: Yes you need to define what host and container share together. Should work with the SHM file too.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch I tried your solution and while it works great on the host, when I split the sender and consumer between host and the container I encountered a problem.
I mounted the volume /tmp in the container but when I run the consumer pipeline I get the following:

`0:00:00.175824440  4723  0x108bf80 LOG                   shmsrc gstshmsrc.c:354:gst_shm_src_create:<shmsrc0> Reading from pipe
shm_open failed on /shmpipe.    9.    0 (2): No such file or directory`
Do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Figured it out. I needed to mount in the container the shared area which is `/dev/shm` by default. It work flawlessly now. Again, thanks for your solution it work great with minimal overhead!

Comment: To elaborate on @mattdibi 's comment, you need to docker run with both -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm and -v /path/to/gst-shm-socket:/tmp/gst-shm-socket, where "gst-shm-socket" is the value you chose for the socket-path property of shmsink/shmsrc.